# Converting log data into csv file with a desirable format

Tags: windows, batch-file

---

I have a log data as:

```
Name:Mark
City:London
Country:UK

Name:Ben
City:Paris
Country:France

Name:Tom
City:Athens
Country:Greece
```

And I need to make a CSV output with the format as:

```
Name   City      Country
Mark   London    UK
Ben    Paris     France
Tom    Athens    Greece
```

The Batch that I have created for this is the simple one to convert to CSV.
Which is as follows:

```
@echo off

cd /d %~dp0
set infilenm=abc.log
set outfilenm=abc.csv
set beforestr=
set afterstr=, 

type nul >%outfilenm%

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

for /f "tokens=1,2,3 delims=" %%A in (%infilenm%) do (   
    set line=%%A      
    echo !line:%beforestr%=%afterstr%!>>%outfilenm%
)
endlocal

exit /b
```

As I am a very new for batch script, can any body help me out for this!

Comment: You've got a wrong logic in your script; `for /F` reads one line after another, so you have to collect the data of three lines before writing one output line...

Comment: That is not a CSV format. CSV stands for Comma Separated Values, though convention allows other delimiters besides comma. CSV allows for variable width values because the comma indicates the end of a value. What you have shown is a fixed width format, which requires you know the maximum length of any field. It also requires you know how to left or right pad your values to a constant width.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have got a wrong logic in your script; [`for /F`](http://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html) reads one line after another, so you have to collect the data of three lines before writing one output line.

Here is an example of how to accomplish your task, not using `for /F` but [input redirection (`<`)](http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-redirection.html) and [`set /P`](http://ss64.com/nt/set.html) to read the log file:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
for /F %%C in ('^< "abc.log" find /C /V ""') do set /A "COUNT=(%%C+1)/2"
set "FIRST=#"
< "abc.log" > "abc.csv" (
    for /L %%I in (1,1,%COUNT%) do (
        set "LINE1=" & set /P LINE1=""
        if defined LINE1 (
            set "LINE2=" & set /P LINE2=""
            set "LINE3=" & set /P LINE3=""
            if defined FIRST (
                echo Name,City,Country
                set "FIRST="
            )
            echo(!LINE1:*:=!,!LINE2:*:=!,!LINE3:*:=!
        )
    )
)
endlocal
```

This relies on the shown format of your log file, so it does not verify the strings left to the colons.

---

Here is a more flexible approach, which is based on the above one, but it collects the field values by their names which are held in a predefined configurable list (constant `_LIST`). One or more empty lines complete a returned row. If a certain field name cannot be found in the currently processed block of the log file, its returned CSV field is empty. This is the code:

```cmd
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions EnableDelayedExpansion

rem // Define constants here:
set "_INPUT=abc.log"  & rem // (log file to process)
set "_OUTPUT=abc.csv" & rem // (CSV file to return)
set "_LIST=Name,City,Country" & rem /* (comma-separated list of field names, which must
                                rem     not contain any of the following characters:
                                rem     `:`, `,`, `*`, `?`, `<`, `>`, `!`, `"`, `=`) */
set "_SEPARATOR=,"    & rem /* (separator character to be used; the default is `,`;
                        rem     the following separator characters are forbidden:
                        rem     `!`, `^`, `&`, `(`, `)`, `<`, `>`, `|`) */
set "_QUOTED=#"       & rem // (if not empty, defines to quote the returned items)
set "_HEADER=#"       & rem // (if not empty, defines to write a header row)

set "_SEPARATOR=!_SEPARATOR!," & set "_SEPARATOR=!_SEPARATOR:~,1!"
if not defined _QUOTED (set "QUOTE=") else set "QUOTE="^" & rem/^"
for /F "delims==" %%D in ('2^> nul set $ARRAY[') do set "%%D="
for /F %%C in ('^< "abc.log" find /C /V ""') do set /A "COUNT=%%C+1"
< "abc.log" > "abc.csv" (
    set "FLAG=" & if defined _HEADER if defined _LIST (
        echo(%QUOTE%!_LIST:,=%QUOTE%%_SEPARATOR%%QUOTE%!%QUOTE%
    ) else echo(%QUOTE%%QUOTE%
    for /L %%I in (1,1,%COUNT%) do (
        set "LINE=" & set /P LINE=""
        if defined LINE (
            for /F "delims=: eol=:" %%J in ("!LINE!") do set "$ARRAY[%%J]=!LINE:*:=!"
            set "FLAG=#"
        ) else (
            if defined FLAG if defined _LIST (
                set "COLL=" & for %%J in ("!_LIST:,=","!") do (
                    set "COLL=!COLL!%_SEPARATOR%%QUOTE%!$ARRAY[%%~J]!%QUOTE%"
                    set "$ARRAY[%%~J]="
                )
                echo(!COLL:~1!
            ) else echo(%QUOTE%%QUOTE%
            set "FLAG="
        )
    )
)
endlocal
exit /B
```

This script collects the list items in some kind of array `$ARRAY[]` whose indexes are the field names, hence the strings left to the (first) colon of every line in a block of the log file, and whose element values are the strings right to the (first) colon, and may look like this (with respect to the first block of your example log data):

> ```cmd
> $ARRAY[Name]=Mark
> $ARRAY[City]=London
> $ARRAY[Country]=UK
> ```

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your logic. The concepts seems working to me.

Comment: But, still there are few things like insteead of 3 lines, I have multiple lines. And in some paragraphs the total number of lines are not resemble to each other. In that case, the loop will be breaked and it gives the mess. So If you have any idea about that, it will be appreciable.

Comment: Please include this information into the question, so future answerers are aware of that immediately. I have a more flexible concept in mind, but I need some time to prepare a script. Do you know all the possible field names (`Name`, `City`, `Country`,...) in advance? can one use the first block to gather all the fields, or does one have to walk through the whole log file to get all of them? (please include the answer to that in your question as well!)

Comment: Hi, fields are all fiexed one and all of them starts with block letters. But out put log(no. of lines) varies as per the action that has been taken for.

Comment: Hi, Thank you so much for your guidance. Your new approach seems working good for me. And the best part is I can modify as per my need. Thank you so much, this means a lot to me. And as you suggested I will try to modify my question too.

Answer (score 1):

```
@echo off
setlocal

set "output=abc.csv"
2> "%output%" echo.

set "line=Name,City,Country"
call :write

for /f "tokens=1,* delims=:" %%A in (abc.log) do call :append %%A %%B
exit /b

:append
setlocal
set  "key=%~1"
set  "value=%~2"
endlocal & (
    if /i "%key%" == "Name" set "line=%value%"
    if /i "%key%" == "City" set "line=%line%,%value%"
    if /i "%key%" == "Country" set "line=%line%,%value%"& call :write
)
exit /b

:write
setlocal
for /f "tokens=1-3 delims=," %%A in ("%line%") do (
    set "a=%%~A          "
    set "b=%%~B          "
    set "c=%%~C          "
)
>> "%output%" echo %a:~,10% %b:~,10% %c:~,10%
set "line="
exit /b
```

The header is written to file first by setting it to the
variable named `line` and calls the label `:write` to format
and write to the csv output file.

The `for` loop splits each line by `:` with tokens `1,*`
to get the 1st token before `:` and the 2nd token as the
remainder after the `:`. It calls the label `:append`
to concatenate the line based on the 1st token. If the
token equals `Country`, then a call to the label `:write`
formats the line and writes it to the csv output file.

Comment: Thanks, but still I need some additional modification to do on it.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is unclear in several points, so we can only guess...

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Put here the width of the output columns
set "width=10"

set "spaces="
for /L %%i in (1,1,%width%) do set "spaces= !spaces!"
set "head=" & "out=" & set "output="
for /F "tokens=1-3 delims=:" %%a in ('findstr /N "^" logData.txt') do (
   if "%%b" neq "" (
      if not defined output (
         set "col=%%b%spaces%"
         set "head=!head!!col:~0,%width%!"
         set "out=!out!^!%%b:~0,%width%^!"
      )
      set "%%b=%%c%spaces%"
   ) else (
      if not defined output (
         echo !head!
         set "output=!out!"
      )
      for /F %%o in ("!output!") do echo %%o
      for %%a in (!head!) do set "%%a=%spaces%"
   )
)
```

With this **logData.txt**:

```
Name:Mark
City:London
Country:UK

Name:Ben
Country:France

Name:Tom
City:Athens

Name:Antonio
City:Mexico
Country:Mexico
```

This is the output:

```
Name      City      Country
Mark      London    UK
Ben                 France
Tom       Athens
Antonio   Mexico    Mexico
```

This program requires that the first group of data include *all* the columns, and that the last group of data be followed by an empty line...

Comment: I can appreciate your ideas. To some instinct, it seems working but could not be as per my need. Though I am trying to modify some areas and try to use this.Thanks.

Comment: As I said, your question is not clear... My code produces the exact same output of your example and it also manages the case when _"in some paragraphs the total number of lines are not resemble to each other"_. Besides, it is a very compact and efficient code. I invite you to clarify "what is your need". IMHO you should appreciate a little more the efforts that other people do to give you _free aid_... **`:(`**

Comment: Sorry for the inconvenience brother. And sorry for my questions again.  As this was my first time in stack, so I could not put my problems properly. Your post gave me some additional Idea. I tried to work with this logic and some other logics provided by those wellwishers and come up with a fruitful output. Thank you very much once again.

Answer (score 1):

A PowerShell solution which doesn't care about the number of address properties.
The only constant it requires is an empty line separating the addresses and
a colon between `property:value`

If needed it could be invoked from a batch (to be more on topic)

- It uses Regular Expression for the splitting into sections
  (addresses),
  to split each section into lines and to split each
  line into property and value.
- it inserts the properties with value into each new address,
- the adjusting of missing properties in the resulting table is done `automagically` by PowerShell
- displaying as a table with column width autodetected by Format-Table

---

```
## Q:\Test\2018\07\04\SO_51166380.ps1
$InputFile = '.\abc.log'
$OutputFile= '.\abc.csv'

$Sections = ((Get-Content $InputFile -Raw) -split "`r?`n *`r?`n" -ne '')

$Csv = ForEach($Section in $Sections){
    $Address = New-Object PSCustomObject
    ForEach($PropVal in ($Section -Split "`r?`n" -ne '')){
        $Prop,$Val = $PropVal.Split(':',2)
        Add-Member -InputObject $Address `
                   -NotePropertyName $Prop `
                   -NotePropertyValue $Val
    }
    $Address
}
$Csv | Format-Table -Auto
$Csv | Export-Csv $OutputFile -NoTypeInformation
```

Sample output with modified abc.log

```
> type abc.log
Name:Mark
City:London
Country:UK
LastName:Anonymus

Name:Ben
Country:France

Name:Tom
City:Athens

Name:Antonio
City:Mexico
Country:Mexico

> .\SO_51166380.ps1

Name    City   Country LastName
----    ----   ------- --------
Mark    London UK      Anonymus
Ben            France
Tom     Athens
Antonio Mexico Mexico

> type .\abc.csv
"Name","City","Country","LastName"
"Mark","London","UK","Anonymus"
"Ben",,"France",
"Tom","Athens",,
"Antonio","Mexico","Mexico",
```

Comment: Wow, this seems simple but good one. Thank you very much for your post.At the beginning I had some issues with execution policies for PS, which I changed and could see the output.Thanks.

Comment: Your question inspired me to evaluate this method  I had in mind for some time. If you find an answer helpful you should consider to [accept the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) and/or [vote up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote)

Comment: Ok. Actually I am not much familier with satck. To be frank this is first time I am involving in it. Thanks again. I will do it.

Comment: Then I sugggest you also take the [tour] and look around in the [help]